# React Native Application error at installing npx bugsnag

Tags: react-native, installation

Error: spawn npm ENOENT

```
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)

at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:464:16)

at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Hello,
Anas Ahmed here, I was installing bugsnag-expo-cli-init in my react native app at first it asked me 3 ques and then at the time of installing it gave me this error can anyone help me in this. Installing in npm

Comment: please do not remove the tags **relevant** to your question. they will better get the attention of people with experience or expertise in helping you. perhaps i am missing something important. please enlighten me with your decision in removing the relevant tags.

Comment: The community told me to remove so i removed

Comment: noted! but it is strange.

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to run the bugsnag-expo-cli on Windows? Bugsnag's Expo CLI currently only supports Linux and Mac:
https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/expo/#installation-and-configuration

As an alternative to the CLI, you could follow the manual integration guide:
https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/expo/manual-setup/